# This java steam does not return the correct value

Tags: java, steam

I want to return the age group, or zero if there is no age, but the hashMap key simply does not show the age 21-23 when there is no age

```java
List<Person> users = Arrays.asList(
    new Person(18, "张三", "123", 1),
    new Person(19, "李四", "124", 0),
    new Person(20, "王五", "125", 1),
    new Person(24, "孙八", "128", 0),
    new Person(27, "周九", "129", 1)
); 
Map<String, Long> group2 = users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(u -> {
            int age = u.getAge();
            if (age >= 18 && age <= 20) { 
                return "18-20"; 
            } else if (age >= 21 && age <= 23) { 
                return "21-23"; 
            } else if (age >= 24 && age <= 26) {
                return "24-26"; 
            } else {
                 return "else"; 
            }
        }), Collectors.counting());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the HashMap with the desired age groups and their counts set to zero.

```
    Map<String, Long> group2 = new HashMap<>();
    group2.put("18-20", 0L);
    group2.put("21-23", 0L);
    group2.put("24-26", 0L);
    group2.put("else", 0L);

    // Update the age group counts using the users list
    Map<String, Long> ageGroupCounts = users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(u -> {
            int age = u.getAge();
            if (age >= 18 && age <= 20) {
                return "18-20";
            } else if (age >= 21 && age <= 23) {
                return "21-23";
            } else if (age >= 24 && age <= 26) {
                return "24-26";
            } else {
                return "else";
            }
        }, Collectors.counting()));

    // Merge the initialized HashMap with the age group counts from the users list
    group2.forEach((key, value) -> ageGroupCounts.merge(key, value, Long::sum));
```

Comment: Your code will get the correct answer in the compiler, thank you

Comment: Streaming programming uses internal iteration, which is one of the core characteristics of streaming programming. This mechanism makes the code written more readable and takes advantage of multi-core processors. which from onjava

Comment: Is java steam better than a for loop？

Comment: @johnson Streams and for loops both have their use cases, Choosing between the two depends on the specific task, readability, and performance requirements, for me the key differences would be Readability, Laziness (Java streams have a lazy evaluation feature) , 
Parallelism ( Java streams can be easily parallelized using the parallelStream() method, which can improve performance in some cases by utilizing multiple processor cores)

and also performance (Java streams can have a slight performance overhead compared to for loops)

Answer (score 4):

You can make default supplier that returns `0` if the group is empty.

```java
List<Person> users = Arrays.asList(
    new Person(18, "张三", "123", 1),
    new Person(19, "李四", "124", 0),
    new Person(20, "王五", "125", 1),
    new Person(24, "孙八", "128", 0),
    new Person(27, "周九", "129", 1)
); 

// Create a default Map with all possible age groups and a count of zero for each age group
Supplier<Map<String, Long>> defaultMapSupplier = () -> Stream.of("18-20", "21-23", "24-26", "else")
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ageGroup -> ageGroup, ageGroup -> 0L));

Map<String, Long> ageCountMap = users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            u -> {
                int age = u.getAge();
                if (age >= 18 && age <= 20) { return "18-20"; }
                else if (age >= 21 && age <= 23) { return "21-23"; }
                else if (age >= 24 && age <= 26) { return "24-26"; }
                else { return "else"; }
            },
            defaultMapSupplier,
            Collectors.counting()
    ));
```

Comment: `ageGroup -> ageGroup` could be replaced by `Function.identity()`.

Comment: I seemed to get an error putting the code into the idea test